# How to judge on start of paragraph

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to find a way to judge my selection range start if is the start of this paragraph

This my code

```
Function isStartPara(selectStart As Integer) As Boolean
If ActiveDocument.Range(Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start, Selection.Paragraphs(1).Range.Start).Start = selecstart Then
    isStartPara = True
Else
    isStartPara = False
End If

End Function
```

Does VBA for word have built-in functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this function or modify its method to your particular needs.

```
Function IsStart() As Boolean
    With Selection
        IsStart = (.Start = .Paragraphs(1).Range.Start)
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: I'm glad you like it. If it helped you please mark my answer as "Selected". Thank you.